# Simple random walk with central limit theorem

Tags: probability, random-walk

have we "random walk" specialist here?

I want proof

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(S_n>\sqrt n log(n)\right)=0$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(|S_n|>\frac{\sqrt(n)}{log(n)}\right)=1$ 
that, which $S_n,$$_{\mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{N_0}$ is a simple random walk.

My Ideas: I want use the central limit theorem
for that i need expectation and the variance.
The transform is difficult for me.

Comment: * $n \in \mathbb{N_0}$

Comment: If it's a simple random walk, isn't the mean of each step 0 and the variance of each step 1?

Comment: Well, i dont know. Are you sure? $E(S_n)=0$ and  $V(S_n)=1$?

Comment: No, $S_n$ is the sum of the random variables, where you end up after $n$ steps.   I'm assuming $S_n=x_1+x_2+...x_n$, and $E(x_i)=0$ and $V(x_i)=1.$

Comment: Thank you very much. $E(S_n)=E \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ and $V(S_n)=V \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$. How can i transform this form to use the central limit theorem?

Comment: Well, does the central limit theory say anything about the distribution of sums of random variables, or about simple functions of their sum?